# Perl tr operator is transliterating based on the variable's name not its value

Tags: perl

I'm using Perl 5.16.2 to try to count the number of occurrences of a particular delimiter in the `$_` string.  The delimiter is passed to my Perl program via the `@ARGV` array.  I verify that it is correct within the program.  My instruction to count the number of delimiters in the string is:

```
$dlm_count = tr/$dlm//;
```

If I hardcode the delimiter, e.g. `$dlm_count = tr/,//;` the count comes out correctly.  But when I use the variable $dlm, the count is wrong.  I modified the instruction to say

```
$dlm_count = tr/$dlm/\t/;
```

and realized from how the tabs were inserted in the string that the operation was substituting every instance of any of the four characters "`$`", "`d`", "`l`", or "`m`" to `\t` — i.e. any of the four characters that made up my variable name `$dlm`.

Here is a sample program that illustrates the problem:

```
$_ = "abcdefghij,klm,nopqrstuvwxyz";
my $dlm = ",";
my $dlm_count = tr/$dlm/\t/;
print "The count is $dlm_count\n";
print "The modified string is $_\n";
```

There are only two commas in the `$_` string, but this program prints the following:

```
The count is 3  
The modified string is abc      efghij,k                ,nopqrstuvwxyz
```

Why is the `$dlm` token being treated as a literal string of four characters instead of as a variable name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `tr` that way, it doesn't interpolate variables.  It runs strictly character by character replacement. So this

```
$string =~ tr/a$v/123/
```

is going to replace every `a` with `1`, every `$` with `2`, and every `v` with `3`.  It is not a regex but a *transliteration*.  From [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)

> Because the transliteration table is built at compile time, neither the SEARCHLIST nor the REPLACEMENTLIST are subjected to double quote interpolation. That means that if you want to use variables, you must use an eval():
>
> ```
> eval "tr/$oldlist/$newlist/";
> die $@ if $@;
> eval "tr/$oldlist/$newlist/, 1" or die $@;
> ```

The above example from docs hints how to count. For `$dlm`s in `$string`

```
$dlm_count = eval "\$string =~ tr/$dlm//";
```

The `$string` is escaped so to not be interpolated before it gets to `eval`.  In your case

```
$dlm_count = eval "tr/$dlm//";
```

---

You can also use tools other than `tr` (or regex). For example, with string being in `$_`

```
my $dlm_count = grep { /$dlm/ } split //;
```

When [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) breaks `$_` by the pattern that is empty string (`//`) it returns the list of all characters in it. Then the [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) block tests each against `$dlm` so returning the list of as many `$dlm` characters as there were in `$_`.  Since this is assigned to a scalar, `$dlm_count` is set to the length of that list, which is the count of all `$dlm`.

Answer (score 3):

In the section of the [docs on perlop 'Quote Like Operators'](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators), it states:

> Because the transliteration table is built at compile time, neither
>   the SEARCHLIST nor the REPLACEMENTLIST are subjected to double quote
>   interpolation. That means that if you want to use variables, you must
>   use an eval():

Answer (score 2):

As documented and as you discovered, `tr///` doesn't interpolate. The simple solution is to use `s///` instead.

```
my $dlm = ",";
$_ = "abcdefghij,klm,nopqrstuvwxyz";
my $dlm_count = s/\Q$dlm/\t/g;
```

If the transliteration is being performed in a loop, the following might speed things up noticeably:

```
my $dlm = ",";
my $tr = eval "sub { tr/\Q$dlm\E/\\t/ }";
for (...) {
   my $dlm_count = $tr->();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although several answers have hinted at the `eval()` idiom for `tr///`, none have the form that covers cases where the string has `tr` syntax characters in it, e.g.- (hyphen):

```
$_ = "abcdefghij,klm,nopqrstuvwxyz";

my $dlm = ",";

my $dlm_count = eval sprintf "tr/%s/%s/", map quotemeta, $dlm, "\t";
```

But as others have noted, there are lots of ways to count characters in Perl that avoid `eval()`, here's another:

```
my $dlm_count = () = m/$dlm/go;
```

Comment: Wow, this is a gold mine of responses.  Thanks to all who replied, I greatly appreciate it.