# perl substitute string characters using a hash and tr

Tags: regex, perl, hash, substitution, tr

I need an efficient way to replace all chars from a string with another char based on a hash map 
Currently I am using regex `s///`  and that is working fine. Can I use `tr` instead , because I just need character by character conversion.

This is what I am trying:

```
my %map = ( a => 9 , b => 4 , c => 8 );
my $str = 'abc';
my $str2 = $str;
$str2 =~ s/(.)/$map{$1}/g;   # $str2 =~ tr /(.)/$map{$1}/  Does not work 


print " $str => $str2\n";
```

Comment: no, can't do that, `tr` isn't regex -- it's _transliteration_.  Read its entry [in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. `tr///` takes neither a regex pattern (`(.)`) nor a string literal (`/$map{$1}/`). You could dynamically build a sub. `my $keys = join '', map quotemeta, keys %map; my $vals = join '', map quotemeta, values %map; my $tr = eval "sub  { $_[0] =~ tr/\Q$keys\E/\Q$vals\E/r }"; my str2 = $tr->($str1);` This *might* be faster if you want to perform the same operation on many long strings.

Comment: Using regex can move past the single character search. `s/(.)/$map{$1}/g` is the right idea, however only the keys should be matched, otherwise if the key is not found an uninitilaized value is thrown. So using the keys only is simply this `$str2 =~ s/([abc])/$map{$1}/g;`

Comment: @x15 good point, where one can also do `s{(.)}{$map{$1}//$1}eg`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to replace exacly 1 character by 1 character, `tr` is ideal for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'abcd';
my $str2 = $str;
$str2 =~ tr /abc/948/;

print " $str => $str2\n";
```

It didn't delete "d", which will happen with the code from your question. Output:

```
abcd => 948d
```

Comment: You can also delete characters like in the original code. Depending on the character set this could do it: `tr/abc\0-\xFF/948/d`

Answer (score 1):

No, one cannot do that with `tr`.  That tool is very different from regex.

Its entry in [*Quote Like Operators* in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) says

> Transliterates all occurrences of the characters found (or not found if the `/c` modifier is specified) in the search list with the positionally corresponding character in the replacement list [...]

and further down it adds

> Characters may be literals, or (if the delimiters aren't single quotes) any of the escape sequences accepted in double-quoted strings. But there is never any variable interpolation, so `"$"` and `"@"` are always treated as literals. [...]

So one surely can't have a hash evaluated, nor match on a regex pattern in the first place.

The lack of even basic variable interpolation is explained at the very end

> ... the transliteration table is built at compile time, ...

We are then told of using [eval](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), with an example, if we must use variables with `tr`.

In this case you'd need to first build variables, one a sequence of characters to replace (`keys`) and the other a sequence of their replacement characters (`values`), and then use them in `tr` via `eval` like in the docs. Better yet, you'd build a sub with it as in ikegami's comment.  Here is a [related page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37358489/4653379).

But this is *the opposite* of finding an approach simpler than that basic regex, the question's point.